# solution for get maximum date from jqx widgets grid

Tags: jquery, widget, jqxgrid

how to select max date from jqx widgets grid

## Date

21/10/2016
20/11/2016
22/10/2016

## output

201/11/2016

Comment: create the `Date()` object for each one and simply compare them.

Answer (score 0):

$.each(data1, function (idx, value) { dts = $.jqx.dataFormat.formatdate(value.Date, 'yyyy/MM/dd', $('#jqxgrid2').jqxGrid('gridlocalization')); maxDate = max(dts); });

function max(dt) { var dates = []; dates.push(new Date(dt)) var maxDate = new Date(Math.max.apply(null, dates)); return maxDate; }